# How to pass multiple objects in a Razor form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to pass two objects via Razor form. How to do that?
Here is my implementation

//controller

```
public string MatchHotel(HotelPairToMatch HotelPair)
{
     return "Hotel matched successfully ";
}
```

//Model

```
public class HotelPairToMatch
{
    public MapHotel NewHotel { get; set; }
    public MapHotel MatchedHotel { get; set; }
}
```

//Template

```
 @foreach (Clarifi.UI.Models.MapHotel hotel in Model.MatchedHotelsList)
 {
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="font13">
         @using (Html.BeginForm("MatchHotel", "MapNewHotel", new {NewHotel=Model.NewHotel,MatchedHotel=hotel }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "pull-left mrs" }))
         {                                
            <input type="submit" value="Match" class="submitLink"/>
         }
       </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use a new class, that contains the classes you want, and send that along to your view.  In MVC, that is known as a `View Model`, and a very appropriate way to send data along to your view.

If that is your controller, you are returning a string, when you should be returning some kind of View(object).

Answer (score 0):

you can submit the objects like this also

In View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MatchHotel", "MapNewHotel", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "pull-left mrs" }))
     {   
        @Html.Hidden("NewHotel ",Model.NewHotel)
         @Html.Hidden("MatchedHotel ","hotel")                 
        <input type="submit" value="Match" class="submitLink"/>
     }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResultMatchHotel(HotelPairToMatch HotelPair)
{
   string newHotel = HotelPair.NewHotel;
   string Hotel = HotelPair.MatchedHotel;
}
```